# Change colors in r plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am currently trying to plot some data and don't manage to obtain a nice result. I have a set of 51 individuals with each a specific value (Pn) and split within 14 groups. The closest thing I end up with is [this kind of plot](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=18/31/yf8c.png). I obtain it thanks to the simple code bellow, starting by ordering my values for the Individuals :

```
Individuals <- factor(Individuals,levels=Individuals[order(Pn)])
dotchart(Pn,label=Individuals,color=Groups)
```

The issue is that I only have 9 colors on this plot (so I lost information somehow) and I can't manage to find a way to apply manually one color per group.

I've also try to use the ggplot2 package by reading it could give nice looking things. In that case I can't manage to order properly the Individuals (the previous sorting doesn't seem to have any effect here), plus I end up with only different type of blue for the group representation which is not an efficient way to represent the information given by my data set. The plot I get is accessible [here](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=18/31/edg2.png) and I used the following code:

```
ggplot(data=gps)+geom_point(mapping=aes(x=Individuals, y=Pn, color=Groups))
```

I apologize if this question seems redundant but I couldn't figure a solution on my own, even following some answer given to others...

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Using the RColorBrewer as suggested bellow [sorted out the issue with the colors](https://zupimages.net/up/18/31/l8su.png) when I use the `ggplot2` package.

Comment: I've worked a bit more on this and I thought I had solved my issue but I still encounter trouble and I don't have a clue about the *why*. Thanks to the code bellow, I approached a bit the result I wished for :
`ggplot(data=gps)+
    geom_bar(mapping=aes(Individuals, y=..Pn.., fill=Groups)) + 
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1), text=element_text(size=13, color="black"))`

But then, I realize that if the bars of the plot are in the right order, the element on the x-axis are still messing up (http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=18/31/b8ik.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `scale_color_manual()` function within `ggplot2`.  You didn't provide a reproducible example, but try something along the lines of this:

```
ggplot(data=gps, mapping=aes(x=Individuals, y=Pn, color=Groups))+
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('GROUP1' = 'color_value_1',
                                  'GROUP2' = 'color_value_2',
                                  'GROUP3' = 'color_value_3'))
```

Replace `GROUPX` with the values inside your Group column, and replace `color_value_x` with whatever colors you want to use.

A good resource for further learning about `ggplot2` is chapter 3 of *R For Data Science*, which you can read here: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Comment: Oh many thanks! I'm sorry for not having given my whole data set, I just don't know how to do such thing here.
I've red this chapter yet and still have trouble especially with the sorting of my individuals. Can't understand why put them as level factors give something meaningful when I don't use the ggplot2 package and just do not make any difference when using the package.

However, thanks for this tip about colors :) It'll definitely help me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without looking at your data, but it looks like `Groups` may be a numeric value. Try this:

```
gps$Groups <- as.factor(gps$Groups)

library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(data=gps)+
geom_point(mapping=aes(x=Individuals, y=Pn, color=Groups))+ 
scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Comment: `Groups` is indeed a numeric value. I've previously try the `as.character` for the groups without further improvement but apparently `as.factor` is working! The Set1 is too short to cover the whole groups but I can see your point :)